# Debugging embedded device

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging, gdb

I work on an embedded device on powerPC with WindRiver linux.
Almost always we debug using the logs. Sometimes gdb, which is really helpful.

But, the process I debug runs with more than 70 threads. 
Using commands to move through the code is a cumbersome process, installing a GUI front end is not an option.

Is there any way that I can have an IDE like ECLIPSE, Netbeans to debug the process, which is running on this embedded device?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdbserver

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that I can have an IDE like ECLIPSE, Netbeans

Yes. Many people debug embedded devices with Eclipse, by using [gdbserver](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html).